# Cumulative Integration with regard to Vasicek Model's Bond Price and its Forward Price

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

### (My Question)

Please show me how to compute the following expectation with its computation process. Besides, $B_t$ is S.B.M.

$$E\left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t \int^u_0 \sigma e^{-b(u-s)} d B_s du \right) \right]$$

(Thank you for your help in advance.)

---

### (Cross-link)

I have posted the same question on https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47522/cumulative-integration-with-regard-to-vasicek-models-bond-price-and-its-forward/47524#47524

---

### (Original Question)

Solve $P(t, T)$ with the following model

$$dr_t=-br_t dt + \sigma dB_t$$

---

### (My consideration)

- Fist,

$$r_u=e^{-bu} r_0 + \int^u_0 \sigma e^{-b(u-s)} dB_s$$

- Second,

\begin{eqnarray}
P(t, T) &=& E \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_u du \right) \middle|  \mathcal{F}_t  \right] \\
&=& E\left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t \left(e^{-bu} r_0 + \int^u_0 \sigma e^{-b(u-s)} dB_s \right) du \right)  \middle|  \mathcal{F}_t  \right] \\
&=& E\left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t e^{-bu} r_0 du - \int^T_t \int^u_0 \sigma e^{-b(u-s)} dB_s   du \right) \middle|  \mathcal{F}_t  \right] \\
&=& \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT}-e^{-bt})  E\left[ \exp \left(- \int^T_t \int^u_0 \sigma e^{-b(u-s)} dB_s   du \right) \middle|  \mathcal{F}_t  \right]
\end{eqnarray}

- Third, I assume to use the following formula, but I cannot have any idea to replace the integration order.

$$E\left[ \exp \left( \int^T_t f(s) dB_s \right) \middle|  \mathcal{F}_t  \right] = \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t f(s)^2 ds \right) $$

### Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### (My answer)

### the Vasicek Bond Price and its Forward Price

- Recall the result of Exercise 5.2.(1) or Exercise 4.5.(10).
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(t, T) &=& E \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_u du \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  \\
  &=& E \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t \left(  e^{-bu} r_0 +  \sigma  \int^u_0 e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s \right) du\right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  \\
  &=& E \left[ \exp \left( - r_0 \int^T_t e^{-bu} du -  \int^T_t\int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s du \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  \\
  &=& E \left[ \exp \left( - r_0 \left[ -\frac{1}{b} e^{-bu} \right]^T_t -  \int^T_t\int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s du \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  \\
  %&=& E \left[ \exp \left(  \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} ) -  \int^T_t\int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s du \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  \\
  &=& \exp \left(  \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} ) \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad E \left[ \exp \left( -  \int^T_t\int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s du \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes the exponential part inside of expectation using the following formula (Cumulative Integration Formula Replacing $du$ and $dB_s$. (Developed on Sep 5, 2019 by Kojima))
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \int^t_0 \int^u_0 dB_s \ du &=& \int^t_0 \int^u_s du \ dB_s  \\
  \int^T_t \int^u_0 dB_s \ du &=& \int^T_0 \int^u_s du \  dB_s - \int^t_0 \int^u_s du \ dB_s 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore,
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && -  \int^T_t\int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s \ du \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad  = -  \int^T_0 \int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s \ du  +  \int^t_0 \int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s \ du \\
  &&  \qquad  = -  \int^T_0 \int^T_s   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)} du \ dB_s  +  \int^t_0 \int^t_s   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)} du \  dB_s \\
  &&  \qquad  =  -  \int^T_0 \left[ -\frac{  \sigma }{b} e^{-b(u-s)} \right]^T_s  dB_s +  \int^t_0 \left[ -\frac{  \sigma }{b} e^{-b(u-s)} \right]^t_s dB_s \\
  &&  \qquad  = \int^T_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s - \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(t-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s \\
  &&  \qquad  = \int^T_t \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad + \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s - \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(t-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above results into the exponential part.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(t, T) &=& \exp \left(  \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} ) \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad E \left[ \exp \left( -  \int^T_t\int^u_0   \sigma e^{-b(u-s)}  dB_s du \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  \\
  &=& \exp \left(  \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} ) \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \ \cdot \exp \left(  \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s - \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(t-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s \right) \\
  && \  E \left[ \exp \left( \int^T_t \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s  \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, use the following formula.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  E\left[ \exp \left( \int^T_t f(s) dB_s \right) \middle|  \mathcal{F}_t  \right] = \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t f(s)^2 ds \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore,
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(t, T) &=& \exp \left(  \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} ) \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \ \cdot \exp \left(  \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s - \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(t-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s \right) \\
  && \  E \left[ \exp \left( \int^T_t \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s  \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t  \right]  \\
  &=& \exp \left(  \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} ) \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \ \cdot \exp \left(  \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s - \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(t-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s \right) \\
  && \ \cdot \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t \frac{  \sigma^2 }{b^2} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)^2  ds  \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- One computes the exponential part with letting it $\mathscr{P}(t, T, r)$. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathscr{P}(t, T, r) &=& \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} )  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s - \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} \left( e^{-b(t-s)} -1 \right)  dB_s \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t \frac{  \sigma^2 }{b^2} \left( e^{-b(T-s)} -1 \right)^2  ds  \\
  &=& \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} )  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b}  e^{-b(T-s)}  dB_s - \int^t_0 \frac{  \sigma }{b} e^{-b(t-s)}  dB_s \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{  \sigma^2 }{2b^2} \int^T_t \left( e^{-2b(T-s)} -2e^{-b(T-s)} + 1 \right) ds  \\
  &=& \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} )  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{1}{b} e^{-bT} e^{bt}\int^t_0  \sigma  e^{-b(t-s)}  dB_s - \frac{1}{b} \int^t_0 \sigma e^{-b(t-s)}  dB_s \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{  \sigma^2 }{2b^2} \left[ \frac{1}{2b} e^{-2b(T-s)} - \frac{2}{b} e^{-b(T-s)} + s \right]^T_t  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, use the result. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \sigma  \int^t_0 e^{-b(t-s)}  dB_s &=& r_t - e^{-bt} r_0 \\
  \mathscr{P}(t, T, r) &=& \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} )  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{1}{b} e^{-bT} e^{bt}\int^t_0  \sigma  e^{-b(t-s)}  dB_s - \frac{1}{b} \int^t_0 \sigma e^{-b(t-s)}  dB_s \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{  \sigma^2 }{2b^2} \left[ \frac{1}{2b} e^{-2b(T-s)} - \frac{2}{b} e^{-b(T-s)} + s \right]^T_t  \\
  &=& \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} )  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{1}{b} e^{-b(T-t)} (r_t - e^{-bt} r_0 )- \frac{1}{b}  (r_t - e^{-bt} r_0 )  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{  \sigma^2 }{2b^2} \frac{1}{2b} ( 1-  e^{-2b(T-t)} ) \nonumber  \\
  &&  \qquad - \frac{  \sigma^2 }{2b^2} \frac{2}{b}  ( 1-  e^{-b(T-t)} )  + \frac{  \sigma^2 }{2b^2}  (T-t)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above results into the exponential part. Hence, one reaches the following result for $P(t, T)$. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(t, T) &=& \exp \left( \frac{r_0}{b} (e^{-bT} -e^{-bt} ) \right) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad \cdot \exp \left( \frac{1}{b} e^{-b(T-t)} (r_t - e^{-bt} r_0 )- \frac{1}{b}  (r_t - e^{-bt} r_0 ) \right) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad \cdot \exp \left(\frac{  \sigma^2 }{4b^3}  ( 1-  e^{-2b(T-t)} ) \nonumber \right) \\
  &&  \qquad \cdot \exp \left( -\frac{  \sigma^2 }{b^3}   ( 1-  e^{-b(T-t)} )  + \frac{  \sigma^2 }{2b^2}  (T-t) \right)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Recall the definition of the forward rate $f(t, T, S)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  f(t, T, S) &\equiv& - \frac{ \log P(t, S) -  \log P(t, T)}{S-T} \\
  f(t, T_1, T_2) &\equiv& - \frac{ \log P(t, T_2) -  \log P(t, T_1)}{T_2-T_1} 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one reaches $-\log P(t, T_2)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  -\log P(t, T_2) &=& - \frac{r_0}{b} e^{-bT_2} + \frac{r_0}{b}  e^{-bt} -\frac{1}{b} e^{-b(T_2-t)} r_t + \frac{1}{b} e^{-b(T_2-t)} e^{-bt} r_0 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \frac{1}{b} r_t -  \frac{1}{b} e^{-bt} r_0 -  \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3} +  \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3} e^{-2b(T_2 -t)} \nonumber \\
  && \qquad  + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^3} -\frac{\sigma^2}{b^3}e^{-b(T_2 -t)} -  \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} T_2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} t  \\
  &=& - \frac{r_0}{b} e^{-bT_2} + \frac{r_0}{b}  e^{-bt} -\frac{1}{b} e^{-b(T_2-t)} r_t + \frac{1}{b} e^{-bT_2}  r_0 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \frac{1}{b} r_t -  \frac{1}{b} e^{-bt} r_0 -  \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3} +  \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3} e^{-2b(T_2 -t)} \nonumber \\
  && \qquad  + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^3} -\frac{\sigma^2}{b^3}e^{-b(T_2 -t)} -  \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} T_2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} t
  \end{eqnarray}
- Moreover, one reaches $\log P(t, T_1)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \log P(t, T_1) &=&  \frac{r_0}{b} e^{-bT_1} - \frac{r_0}{b}  e^{-bt}  + \frac{1}{b} e^{-b(T_1-t)} r_t - \frac{1}{b} e^{-bT_1}  r_0 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad - \frac{1}{b} r_t + \frac{1}{b} e^{-bt} r_0 + \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3} -  \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3} e^{-2b(T_1 -t)} \nonumber \\
  && \qquad  - \frac{\sigma^2}{b^3} + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^3}e^{-b(T_1 -t)} +  \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} T_1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} t
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore, one reaches the following equation.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  -\log P(t, T_2) + \log P(t, T_1) &=& - \frac{r_t}{b} ( e^{-b(T_2-t)} - e^{-b(T_1-t)} ) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3}  ( e^{-2b(T_2-t)} - e^{-2b(T_1-t)} ) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad - \frac{\sigma^2}{b^3} ( e^{-b(T_2-t)} - e^{-b(T_1-t)} ) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad - \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} (T_2 -T_1) \\
  &=& - \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2} (T_2 -T_1)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad - \left( \frac{r_t}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^3}  \right) ( e^{-b(T_2-t)} - e^{-b(T_1-t)} )  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3}  ( e^{-2b(T_2-t)} - e^{-2b(T_1-t)} ) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Hence, substitute the above result into the definition of the forward rate $f(t, T_1, T_2)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  f(t, T_1, T_2) &\equiv& - \frac{ \log P(t, T_2) -  \log P(t, T_1)}{T_2-T_1} \\
  &=& - \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2}  - \frac{1}{T_2 -T_1 } \left( \frac{r_t}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^3}  \right) ( e^{-b(T_2-t)} - e^{-b(T_1-t)} )  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \frac{1}{T_2 -T_1 }  \frac{\sigma^2}{4b^3}  ( e^{-2b(T_2-t)} - e^{-2b(T_1-t)} ) 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

### (Cumulative Integration Formula Replacing $du$ and $dB_s$)

- ### I have developed formulas to solve this by myself!

\begin{eqnarray}
\int^t_0 \int^u_0 dB_s \ du &=& \int^t_0 \int^u_s du \ dB_s  \\
\int^T_t \int^u_0 dB_s \ du &=& \int^T_0 \int^u_s du \  dB_s - \int^t_0 \int^u_s du \ dB_s 
\end{eqnarray}

- ### Therefore, we can use the following formula as I assume.

$$E\left[ \exp \left( \int^T_t f(s) dB_s \right) \middle|  \mathcal{F}_t  \right] = \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t f(s)^2 ds \right) $$

- ### I solved the Vasicek Bond Price computation using the formulas.

Comment: I will show the computation process for $P(t, T)$ on this model, later.